# TypeLoadException because of a file in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, typeloadexception

I keep getting this error

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'projectname.AuthenticationApi.Controllers.LoggedOutViewModel' from assembly 'projectname.AuthenticationApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

It doesnt make sense to me. Once I have this project referenced in another project I get this error. If I dont have it referenced there is no error and all is well. I am making an asp.net core api which references this project. Everytime I try to start it I get this error. If I dont reference it there is no error.

I looked in the controller file it mentions and there doesnt seem to be anything wrong there since its working when its not referenced.

Comment: Often this sort of error is resolved by clearing out bin and obj folders and doing a clean/rebuild.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior took your advice to clean the solution and rebuild it. now its giving me http error 502.5 process failure .

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/945 ?